# Make a search for a word in a mediumblob file in database?

Tags: php, database, file, search

I have in my database :

```
name               mime        size       data

Untitled.txt     text/plain    bigint(20)    Mediumblob
```

And i want to search in i the file for a word i did get for a search command.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps extract the file from the database and use fopen/fread functions.

Would probably be better to add a new column which is a text format. So when adding a record use fopen/fread to get the data from the file and insert it into a TEXT column. Then search via this field.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE textmime LIKE '%searchinput%'
```

Where 'textmime' is the column where the text version of the file is stored.

Just an idea

Comment: If you already have tons of records then make a script that loops through them and adds the text data to the new column